# PHP JWT Invalid signature

Tags: php, jwt, encode, signature

Given this code:

```
function base64url_encode($data) {
    return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '=');
}

$key = 'secret';

//setting the header: 'alg' => 'HS256' indicates that this token is signed using HMAC-SHA256
$header = array(
    'alg' => 'HS256',
    'typ' => 'JWT'
);

// Returns the JSON representation of the header
$header = json_encode($header); 

//encodes the $header with base64.  
$header = base64url_encode($header);

$payload = array("a" => "b");

$payload = json_encode($payload);       
$payload = base64url_encode($payload);

$signature = hash_hmac('SHA256','$header.$payload', $key, true);
$signature = base64url_encode($signature); 

echo "$header.$payload.$signature";
```

Returns the following JWT:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhIjoiYiJ9.rhCKIvkwiuNcchxDZnGak8XT1q8lmLhnm8aIxzUioWg
```

But the signature is not verified at https://jwt.io/
The payload is decrypted well though... What may be the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using single quotes around `$header.payload` when calculating the HMAC, rather than double quotes; the former uses the literal string and does not expand the variables:

```
$signature = hash_hmac('SHA256', "$header.$payload", $key, true);
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast! Thanks, that was it! Basic PHP knowledge I guess, but I come from JS :(